# Mapping discrete domain into contiuos domain

Tags: c++

I am mapping a continuous domain into a discrete domain. In this way, I have a vector `v1` composed of random values. Each index of this vector can represent a particular value (e.g., index 0 represents `id` 999). To translate `v1` into `v2`, first I copy `v1` into `v1.1` and sort it in ascending order. Then, for each element in `v1.1` I search its position at `v1` and include its index into `v2` as showed bellow.

```
index     1,    1,    2,    2,    3
v1   = {0.1, 0.22, 0.99, 0.22, 0.55}
v1.1 = {0.1, 0.22, 0.22, 0.55, 0.99}
v2   = {  1,    1,    2,    3,    2}
```

What is an efficient way do it since repeated values may be present in `v1`?

Comment: The procedure appears to involve sorting `v1`. What should happen when two `v1` elements are equal, but their corresponding `index` values are different? What should appear in `v2`? E.g. `v1={1.0, 1.0}; index={2, 1}` - should `v2` be `{1, 2}`, or `{2, 1}`, or either and it doesn't matter which?

Comment: Read the comment. I'm asking for clarification of what the output should be in this exact case. The problem as stated appears under-specified.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik in case equal values appear in v1, each one representing a different index, each value should be mapped to v2 respecting its corresponding index. Since `v1.1` is mapped from left to right, an easy way to do it would be mapping each value and removing it from the vector. But that seems ineficient.

Comment: Yes - but in what order? I gave a specific example in the comment - what should the output be for that example?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I am using lower_bound to find the value, so when I search for the value in `v1`, it is giving me the first appearance of the value from left to right. To answer your question, 1.0 and 1.0 respective to 2 and 1 would first put 2 into v2, then 1 into v2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
st::vector<int> v2(v1.size());
std::iota(v2.begin(), v2.end(), 0);
std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end(),
  [&](int pos1, int pos2) {
    return std::tie(v1[pos1], pos1) < std::tie(v1[pos2], pos2);
  }
);
std::transform(v2.begin(), v2.end(), v2.begin(),
  [&](int pos) { return index[pos]; }
);
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/XSGRDG59809)

Comment: the repeated values should be considered. The problem is to create a way to translate it considering repeated values. Ok, the creating of the vectors can be done considering that repeated values will not be present. However, I will perform operations in this vectors in a way that, sometimes, repeated values will be present in `v1`.

Comment: My code does too consider repeated values. Try it, see for yourself.